# Problema com menu

Tags: html, css

Ao passar com o cursor em cima de sobre este fica azul e queria que permanece-se azul enquanto estive-se com o cursor em cima do submenu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código:

```css
 menu
 { 
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
 }

 menu ul
 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 menu li
 {
  float:left;
 }

 menu li a, #menu li span
 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 1.5em 1em 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.10em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 menu li a:hover
 {
  color: dodgerblue;
 }
 menu li a:hover
 {
  color: dodgerblue;
 }
 menu li ul li 
 {
  color: dodgerblue;
 }

 menu li:hover
 {
  color: dodgerblue;
  background:white;      
 }
 menu li ul
 {
  display: none;  
 }
 menu li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:20;
  color: dodgerblue;
 } 
 menu li ul
 {
  color: dodgerblue;
 }
 menu li:hover li{
  float:none;
 }
 menu li ul li{
  display:block;
  background: black;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="?op=5" accesskey="5" title="">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="?op=1" accesskey="2" title="">Convocatórias</a></li>
  <li><a href="?op=2" accesskey="3" title="">Atas</a></li>
  <li><a href='?op=6' accesskey='5' title=''>+ Utilizador</a></li> 
  <li><a href="logout.php">Sessao</a>
    <ul  style="text-decoration: none;float:none;width:120px">
      <li><a href="#" style=" background: black; width: 120px;text-decoration: none;">Informacao</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="background: black;width: 120px;text-decoration: none;">Definicões</a></li>
      <li><a href="logout.php" style="background: black;width: 120px;text-decoration: none;">Terminar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no seu css, esse `menu`, seria um `class`, um `id`, ou a tag `menu`?

Comment: é id, #menu ...

Comment: em `sessao`, tente retirar o link, e deixe o texto apenas dentro do `li`

Comment: retirei link, coloquei numa div para formatar e ficou direito. O width do background a que muda a entrar em convocatoria e ata, suspeito que seja por ter la outro css(bootstrap), nao devia alterar porque convocatoria esta como include mas como recarrega a pagina

Esta optimo obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: retirei a cor de fundo dos li e coloquei no ul e resolveu